# Unit test case to mock postgresql Connection and statements in SCALA

Tags: postgresql, scala

I am very much new to Scala and need to write a test case which will mock the Postgresql connections and Statements.However unable to do so and getting the error.Can anyone help me.Below is the code that I've written
Thanks in advance !!

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StringType, StructField, StructType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column`
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import java.nio.file.Paths
import java.sql.ResultSet
import java.io.InputStream
import java.io.Reader
import java.util
import java.io.File
import java.util.UUID
import java.nio.file.attribute.PosixFilePermission
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SQLContext}
import org.scalatest.{Matchers, WordSpecLike, BeforeAndAfter}
import org.scalactic.{Good, Bad, Many, One}
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import spark.jobserver.{SparkJobValid, SparkJobInvalid}
import spark.jobserver.api.{JobEnvironment, SingleProblem}
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Column, Row, DataFrame}
import java.sql.Connection
import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.ResultSet
import org.junit.Assert
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.easymock.EasyMock.expect
import org.powermock.api._
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest
import java.io.FileReader
import org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito._
import org.postgresql.copy.CopyManager
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import org.mockito.Matchers.any
import java.sql.Statement

class mockCopyManager(){

def copyIn(command : String , fR:java.io.FileReader) :Unit ={
println("Run Command {}".format(command))
}

}

class AdvisoretlSpec extends WordSpecLike    with Matchers  with     
MockFactory {
val sc = SparkUnitTestContext.hiveContext
import SparkUnitTestContext.defaultSizeInBytes


"Class Advisoretl job" should {

"load data in "{

  val csvMap : Map[String,String] = Map("t1"->"t1.csv","t2"->"t2.csv")
  val testObj = new Advisoretl()
  val mockStatement = mock[Statement]
  val mockConnection=mock[Connection]
  val a:String = "TRUNCATE TABLE t1"
  val b:String = "TRUNCATE TABLE t2"
  PowerMockito.mockStatic(classOf[DriverManager])
  val mockCopyManager=mock[CopyManager]
  PowerMockito.when(DriverManager.getConnection(any[String]), Nil: _*).thenReturn(mockConnection)
  (mockConnection.createStatement _).when().returns(mockStatement)
  (mockStatement.executeUpdate _).when(a).returns(1)
  (mockStatement.executeUpdate _).when("TRUNCATE TABLE t2").returns(1)
  (mockCopyManager.copyIn _).when(*).returns(1)*/
  val fnResult = testObj.connectionWithPostgres("a", "b", "c", "target/testdata", csvMap)
  fnResult should be ("OK")

}
  }
}'
```

Comment: unfortunately I can't see any code...

Comment: apologies,i hoe you can see the code now !!

Comment: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
[error] both method executeUpdate in trait Statement of type (x$1: String, x$2: Array[String])Int
[error] and  method executeUpdate in trait Statement of type (x$1: String, x$2: Array[Int])Int
[error] match expected type ?
[error]       (mockStatement.executeUpdate _).when(a).returns(1)
[error]                      ^
[error] one error found
[error] (test:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Jul 4, 2017 10:44:23 AM

Comment: Above is the error

Comment: You can have a look at [Acolyte framework](http://acolyte.eu.org/) for "really isolated" unit tests about JDBC persistence

Comment: add the error message to the question,  and format it properly. Nobody's going to parse what you have in the comment.